# python issue with super

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn some python and the new style class constructor doesn't seem to be working with super.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello A'

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello B'
        super(A, self).__init__()

a = A();
b = B();
```

When I run this program, I get the following:

```
$ python classa.py
Hello A
Hello B
```

It should say

```
Hello A
Hello B
Hello A
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using python 2.7.6 on a Mac.

Comment: try super(B, self).__init__() inside class B(A)

Comment: If you are using Python 3 the easiest way is to omit the parameters of _super_: `super().__init__()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing `super(A, self).__init__()` it should be `super(B, self).__init__()`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong class to the call to `super`. A call to `super` returns a proxy object whose MRO (method resolution order) consists of the classes *after* the class passed as the first object. Here are the MROs for each class:

```
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

When you call `super(A, self).__init__`, you are really invoking `object.__init__`, not `A.__init__`. `object.__init__` doesn't output anything to the screen.

Changing the call to `super(B, __init__)` causes `A.__init__` to run in your example.

Incidentally, good design dictates that if you use `super` in one class in your hierarchy, you need to call it in *all* the classes in your hierarchy.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print 'Hello A'

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello B'
        super(A, self).__init__()
```

Due to how `super` works (despite it's name, it does *not* necessarily call a method on the class's parent), this is required for the calls to work correctly in the case of multiple inheritance.